# current domain linked to email hosting, wish to add different web hosting

Tags: dns, hosting, web-hosting, domain-name, nameservers

I have setup web-hosting for the domain name, 'www.domainName.com' (forExample) and had it working fine, but when I removed the existing nameservers and placed in my web-hosting nameServers, it broke the 3rd party email hosting, which unbeknown to me was actively being used. To rectify this, my nameServers were removed, and the mail-hosting namerServers were added back:

ab1_mailNameServer_etc
ab2_mailNameServer_etc

Nothing else was changed but I now get a 'ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED' error when i venture to the 'www.domainName.com' through my browser.

I looked up the domain A-Records using MXtoolBox and it tells me that no name servers can be found, although i have an A-Record for, domainName.com & www.domainName.com that point to the correct IP. I also have the correct A-Records in my hosting, and i know this because this all worked before my hosting nameServers were removed.

My question is, can I simply add back in my web-hosting nameServers under the existing email nameServers without breaking email-hosting link?

I am a lil frightened to do so, as I cannot risk breaking the email twice in one week.

Thanks in advance peeps! ;)

Answer (score 0):

After changing back to mail-hosting's nameservers, if your emails have started working, then there's no problem with DNS propagation. In this case, an error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" is more likely a local computer problem and can be fixed by the flushing DNS and clearing the browse cache/cookies.

As long as primarily set nameservers (mail-hosting nameservers) are resolving correctly, adding hosting nameservers under to existing won't create any difference.

Comment: @accuwebhosting-com - Thank you for your reply! I have just added back in the 'standard domain namerservers' in along with the existing 'mail nameservers'.. The changes are quite fresh, but I have inspected the domain with MXtools.com and I can see that it now picking up an A-Record pointing to the correct web hosting IP I also did MX-Record test, but the mail nameserver is nowhere to be seen and it is only picking up the web-hosting nameserver, also tells me that 'no mx record exists'..? 

Like i said the changes are still quite, and it has propagated on some networks, but not others.

Comment: Be sure that MX records are correctly set in mail nameservers. If multiple MX records are there, make sure that your desired MX are set with the lowest priority (0). You can also ask your service provider for the same.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you can only have one set of nameservers (not sure if that's across the board, or just with this registrar) listed, then you need to add the 'MX entry', relevant CNAME, TXT-Records in your web hosting via cPanel and ur mail and web hosting should work in unity. Peace, hope that helps someoene, cause it took me freakn ages to find that out!